# How do I subtract a group of rows based on a selected value (within that group of rows) with a specific identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, multi-index

I'm not sure if I should approach this with a groupby , idx or even take the extra step to make this dataframe into a multi-index data frame but I hope the example will clearly convey what I'm having trouble with.(shown below is in multi index form)

I have a dataframe (df) as shown below and I would like to subtract each group of doses by their respective Empty average value and put the values into a new column called 'norm'.

```
Chem ID  Dose     average
A    23  Control  0.45
         Empty    0.33
         Positive 0.55
         1mM      0.66
B    24  Control  0.67
         Empty    0.45
         Positive 0.80
         1mM      0.70
C    26  Control  0.66
         Empty    0.50
         Positive 0.78
         1mM      0.66
D    29  Control  0.54
         Empty    0.24
         Positive 0.33
         1mM      0.78
E    30  Control  0.66
         Empty    0.40
         Positive 0.76
         1mM      0.56
F    35  Control  0.67
         Empty    0.32
         Positive 0.43
         1mM      0.44
```

Here is the desired output:

```
Chem ID  Dose     average norm
A    23  Control  0.45    0.12
         Empty    0.33    0.00
         Positive 0.55    0.22
         1mM      0.66    0.33
B    24  Control  0.67    0.22
         Empty    0.45    0.00
         Positive 0.80    0.35
         1mM      0.70    0.25
C    26  Control  0.66    0..16
         Empty    0.50    0.00
         Positive 0.78    0..28
         1mM      0.66    0.16
D    29  Control  0.54    0.30
         Empty    0.24    0.00
         Positive 0.33    0.09
         1mM      0.78    0.54
E    30  Control  0.66    0.26
         Empty    0.40    0.00
         Positive 0.76    0.36
         1mM      0.56    0.16
F    35  Control  0.67    0.35
         Empty    0.32    0.00
         Positive 0.43    0.11
         1mM      0.44    0.12
```

I have been scouring for a similar question and have only come close to subtracting by the the min by using a groupby approach. However, all chems dont have Empty as their lowest value so the min approach wouldn't work. I would like to somehow specify subtracting by the respective 'Empty' for each chem and id. Any help would be much appreciated!

df['norm']= df.groupby(['Chem','ID'])['average'].transform(lambda x: x- x.min())

Answer (score 2):

You can set the index to `['Chem','ID']`, filter by `Dose='Empty'`, and then do a self-join:

```
df = df.set_index(['Chem','ID'])
df_empty = df[df['Dose'] == 'Empty'].groupby(level=[0,1]).agg({'average':'mean'})
df2 = df.merge(df_empty, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={'average_x':'average', 'average_y':'average_empty'})
df2['norm'] = df2['average'] - df2['average_empty']
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
             Dose  average  average_empty  norm
Chem ID                                        
A    23   Control     0.45           0.33  0.12
     23     Empty     0.33           0.33  0.00
     23  Positive     0.55           0.33  0.22
     23       1mM     0.66           0.33  0.33
B    24   Control     0.67           0.45  0.22
     24     Empty     0.45           0.45  0.00
     24  Positive     0.80           0.45  0.35
     24       1mM     0.70           0.45  0.25
C    26   Control     0.66           0.50  0.16
     26     Empty     0.50           0.50  0.00
     26  Positive     0.78           0.50  0.28
     26       1mM     0.66           0.50  0.16
D    29   Control     0.54           0.24  0.30
     29     Empty     0.24           0.24  0.00
     29  Positive     0.33           0.24  0.09
     29       1mM     0.78           0.24  0.54
E    30   Control     0.66           0.40  0.26
     30     Empty     0.40           0.40  0.00
     30  Positive     0.76           0.40  0.36
     30       1mM     0.56           0.40  0.16
F    35   Control     0.67           0.32  0.35
     35     Empty     0.32           0.32  0.00
     35  Positive     0.43           0.32  0.11
     35       1mM     0.44           0.32  0.12
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic about getting the `min` is right, you just need a temporary column based on `Dose` before computing the mean

```py
norm = df.average.where(df.Dose.eq('Empty'))
norm = norm.groupby([df.Chem, df.ID]).transform('min')
df.assign(norm = df.average - norm)

   Chem    ID      Dose  average  norm
0     A  23.0   Control     0.45  0.12
1     A  23.0     Empty     0.33  0.00
2     A  23.0  Positive     0.55  0.22
3     A  23.0       1mM     0.66  0.33
4     B  24.0   Control     0.67  0.22
5     B  24.0     Empty     0.45  0.00
6     B  24.0  Positive     0.80  0.35
7     B  24.0       1mM     0.70  0.25
8     C  26.0   Control     0.66  0.16
9     C  26.0     Empty     0.50  0.00
10    C  26.0  Positive     0.78  0.28
11    C  26.0       1mM     0.66  0.16
12    D  29.0   Control     0.54  0.30
13    D  29.0     Empty     0.24  0.00
14    D  29.0  Positive     0.33  0.09
15    D  29.0       1mM     0.78  0.54
16    E  30.0   Control     0.66  0.26
17    E  30.0     Empty     0.40  0.00
18    E  30.0  Positive     0.76  0.36
19    E  30.0       1mM     0.56  0.16
20    F  35.0   Control     0.67  0.35
21    F  35.0     Empty     0.32  0.00
22    F  35.0  Positive     0.43  0.11
23    F  35.0       1mM     0.44  0.12
```

Breakdown:

- Create a temporary column for average values where Dose is Empty

```py
norm = df.average.where(df.Dose.eq('Empty'))
print(norm)
0      NaN
1     0.33
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5     0.45
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      NaN
9     0.50
10     NaN
11     NaN
12     NaN
13    0.24
14     NaN
15     NaN
16     NaN
17    0.40
18     NaN
19     NaN
20     NaN
21    0.32
22     NaN
23     NaN
Name: average, dtype: float64
```

- Extend the value to all groups - this is achieved via a combination of groupby and transform (since we are dealing with `min` - `max` can be used as well - pandas is smart enough to avoid the nulls):

```py
In [126]: norm = norm.groupby([df.Chem, df.ID]).transform('min')

In [127]: norm
Out[127]: 
0     0.33
1     0.33
2     0.33
3     0.33
4     0.45
5     0.45
6     0.45
7     0.45
8     0.50
9     0.50
10    0.50
11    0.50
12    0.24
13    0.24
14    0.24
15    0.24
16    0.40
17    0.40
18    0.40
19    0.40
20    0.32
21    0.32
22    0.32
23    0.32
Name: average, dtype: float64
```

Since pandas already aligns on index, we can safely continue with the computation:

```py
In [128]: norm = df.average - norm

In [129]: norm
Out[129]: 
0     0.12
1     0.00
2     0.22
3     0.33
4     0.22
5     0.00
6     0.35
7     0.25
8     0.16
9     0.00
10    0.28
11    0.16
12    0.30
13    0.00
14    0.09
15    0.54
16    0.26
17    0.00
18    0.36
19    0.16
20    0.35
21    0.00
22    0.11
23    0.12
Name: average, dtype: float64
```

You can then reassign back to the original dataframe:

```py
df.assign(norm=norm)
   Chem    ID      Dose  average  norm
0     A  23.0   Control     0.45  0.12
1     A  23.0     Empty     0.33  0.00
2     A  23.0  Positive     0.55  0.22
3     A  23.0       1mM     0.66  0.33
4     B  24.0   Control     0.67  0.22
5     B  24.0     Empty     0.45  0.00
6     B  24.0  Positive     0.80  0.35
7     B  24.0       1mM     0.70  0.25
8     C  26.0   Control     0.66  0.16
9     C  26.0     Empty     0.50  0.00
10    C  26.0  Positive     0.78  0.28
11    C  26.0       1mM     0.66  0.16
12    D  29.0   Control     0.54  0.30
13    D  29.0     Empty     0.24  0.00
14    D  29.0  Positive     0.33  0.09
15    D  29.0       1mM     0.78  0.54
16    E  30.0   Control     0.66  0.26
17    E  30.0     Empty     0.40  0.00
18    E  30.0  Positive     0.76  0.36
19    E  30.0       1mM     0.56  0.16
20    F  35.0   Control     0.67  0.35
21    F  35.0     Empty     0.32  0.00
22    F  35.0  Positive     0.43  0.11
23    F  35.0       1mM     0.44  0.12
```

Comment: Awesome this works very well! Thank you I've been stuck on this for awhile! Can you breakdown what's going on a bit? I would like to understand what's going on in the background a bit more as opposed to just getting the answer and running away with it.